# UpdateCommand in Gridview DataSource returns an error ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datasource, sql-update

I have a GridView that pulls the data from an Oracle DataBase dynamically.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvData" runat="server" DataSourceID="DS" CellPadding="4" 
        ForeColor="#333333" AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="True" 
        ShowFooter="True" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" 
        AutoGenerateEditButton="True" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True"
        OnRowDataBound="gvData_RowDataBound"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvData_SelectedIndexChanged" 
        OnRowUpdating="gvData_RowUpdating" OnRowUpdated="gvData_RowUpdated"
        OnRowDeleting="gvData_RowDeleting" OnRowDeleted="gvData_RowDeleted">
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" 
            ForeColor="#333333" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    </asp:GridView>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DS" runat="server">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

It works fine with SELECT/INSERT/DELETE statements, however when it comes to UPDATE statement , it returns an error **ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number**

```
protected void gvData_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    double number;
    List<string> text = new List<string>();
    List<string> pkParam = new List<string>();
    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();

    for (int i = 1; i < gvData.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        try 
        {
            lb = (LinkButton)gvData.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Controls[0];
            tb = (TextBox)gvData.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[i].Controls[0];

            if (tb.Text.Length > 0 && !Settings.PK.Contains(lb.Text))
                if(Double.TryParse(tb.Text.ToText(), out number))
                    text.Add(lb.Text + " = " + number);
                else
                    text.Add(lb.Text + " = " + "'" + tb.Text.ToText() + "'");
        }
        catch { }
    }

    foreach (string pk in Settings.PK)
    {
        pkParam.Add(pk + " = :" + pk);
        DS.UpdateParameters.Add(
            new Parameter(pk, TypeCode.String, e.Keys[pk].ToString()));
    }

    DS.UpdateCommand = string.Format("UPDATE {0} SET {1} WHERE {2}",
        Settings.TABLE, string.Join(",", text.ToArray()), 
            string.Join(" AND ", pkParam.ToArray()));
 }
```

The code of RowUpdate doesn't really matter. I would write ANY update statement and it would return the same error.
Any ideas, folks? Thank you beforehands!

Sample query:

```
DS.UpdateCommand = "UPDATE ATDB.CTD_PROBLEM_EDIT_V SET CUTTING_COMMENTS = 'rrr'";
```

PK:

```
public static string[] PK = new string[] { "PROBLEM_DEPTH_MD", "API", "BUS_AREA_ID" };
```

Comment: I'm not convinced the code is a problem. You say that any UPDATE statement would fail. Can you provide an example of a SQL statement that would fail? It would also help to see the values in Settings.PK?

Comment: see edit. I tested this query (and many others) in PL/SQL Developer - it works. Even if I put "UPDATE" in the DS.UpdateCommand, it would give me the same error. And it doesn't really matter what the primiry key here is; I could use a different table with different keys. Note: delete statement uses same Settings.PK and works fine.

Comment: Just some style suggestions: get rid of the color declarations and use CSS, make the aspx code slightly cleaner; Use NLog and put a log statement out inside the catch block - many errors are found when you are aware an exception is thrown.

Comment: Does it make any performance difference to put it in CSS? I was going to put it in CSS but never got to it... And how do I use the NLog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my way around the problem. Not the best one but acceptable.
Instead of `DS.UpdateCommand` I use OracleCommand simply ignoring Exception about setting UpdateCommand.

```
protected void gvData_RowUpdated(object sender, GridViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Exception != null)
        e.ExceptionHandled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because dataKeyNames will be added as Parameters to updateCommand automatically,so the parameters count will not be equal between the command_text and the dataSource.
You need to remove them before do update

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a dev environment setup at home, so I can't check my suggestion. See if the placing this on your sqlDataSource works for you. ConflictDetection="OverwriteChanges"

**Example:**

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="DS" ConflictDetection="OverwriteChanges" runat="server">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**UPDATE:**

Another possibility is that one of your parameter names is too long. The limit is 31 or 32 characters in length. In the past when I was dynamically creating a parameter list, I would just give the corresponding parameter name a generic name (eg. Param[x]) and increment the parameter name with the loop (eg. Param1, Param2, Param3, and so on for each parameter that needed to be in the statement). Some other suggestions would be to verify that your parameter names being used from your header are valid (ie. no spaces).

My last thought would be that the SqlDataSource is not compatible. Are you using System.Data.OracleClient OR Oracle.DataAccess.Client? Try using a different provider to see if that makes a difference.

See these articles for additional help. That's about all I got. Sorry!

[Oracle.DataAccess.Client and SqlDataSource in ASP.NET](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=620971)

[update on gridview produces ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number](http://kr.forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=433587)

**UPDATE:**
As suggested above, try to switch your data provider, in this case, try ODP.NET. You will have to install it. It is not a system library. Looking to use ODBC with Oracle may be another option. In any case, you probably are left with no options but to not use anything with System.Data.OracleClient.

[Fixed! Oracle 11G and SqlDataSource: The ugly 'ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number' Issue](http://weblogs.asp.net/kencox/archive/2008/02/25/fixed-oracle-11g-and-sqldatasource-the-ugly-ora-01036-illegal-variable-name-number-issue.aspx)

[Oracle Data Provider for .NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html)

Comment: This is set by default. And I've tried setting it in both .apsx and .asp

Comment: The problem is not in parameters. I can use a statement without ane parameter or just write "UPDATE" in the command. It would still give me the same error.
I use System.Data.OracleClient, I don't have the other one in my reference list. Thanks for the links, I'll look at them now.

Comment: When I set the gridview provider to Oracle.DataAccess.Client, I get an error: "Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed". And links didnt really help.. I've done those things. But thanks much

Comment: See final suggestion and links for ODP.NET. You will have to install it. I wish I could be of more of a help. It has been several months, since I messed with Oracle, purely SQL Server now. In my past job, we were not using one of the providers, because it was no longer supported or being developed. I just couldn't remember which one. Best of luck.